# round down numbers to the next 5 in python

Tags: python, numbers, rounding

I want to round numbers down to the next 5 in python
What I mean:

```
1 -> 0
3 -> 0
4 -> 0
5 -> 5
7 -> 5
9 -> 5
...
```

I already searched a lot for rounding numbers with a base but then also `3 -> 5` but it has to be `3 -> 0`

Thank you for helping me with this

Answer (score 4):

Simply subtract the remainder of the integer division by 5:

```
n - n % 5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Python 2:

```
def func(n):
    return (n / 5) * 5
```

If you're on Python 3:

```
def func(n):
    return (n // 5) * 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Less hacky / more Pythonian to use math.floor, like this:

```
from math import floor

def floor5(x):
  return floor(x/5)*5

# Test:
print(list(map(floor5, [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9])))
```

Output

```
[0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5]
```